# How do I launch a specific (explicit) activity of another app

Tags: java, android-intent, android-activity, launch

I want to launch a specific activity of another app from my app. For example, on the `onCreate` of my app, I want to launch the activity named `Rolling` (not main) activity of `com.pas.webcam.pro`. I have heard that you must have control of both apps to do this because you must add an intent filter to the manifest of the second app. This is not true though, because activity launcher apps in the Google Play Store can launch the Rolling Activity of IP Webcam Pro.

The [Activity Launcher app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher) is open source, so I tried reviewing the [source code here](https://github.com/butzist/ActivityLauncher!!). It was too complicated though, so I could not figure out how this app magically launches this activity. There are many other questions like this on Stack Overflow, and I have read every one. I have also tried lots of the code from the answers too, like this:

`Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.pas.webcam", "com.pas.webcam.RollingActivity")); startActivity(intent);`

I have also tried variants of this code from other posts. My app always crashes and I get variants (depending on the code I use) of [the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwQNj.jpg):

> An error occurred

> Invalid intent operation. Unable to find explicit activity class {com.pas.webcam.pro/com.pas.webcam.pro.Rolling}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I have put both of the following in my Android Manifest and the same thing happens:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_INSTALLED_PACKAGES" />`

`<activity android:name="com.pas.webcam.pro.RollingActivity"`

Thanks in advance for any answers, I really appreciate it, as I have been working on this problem for a while.

Edit: Here is the activity of the app I want to launch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa7Xq.jpg

Edit: David Wasser helped me solve the problem by giving me the code neccessary to solve the problem. It actually works! To anyone who wants to launch a specific activity of another app with code, please use this:

`Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setClassName("com.pas.webcam.pro", "com.pas.webcam.Rolling"); startActivity(intent);`

You may replace com.pas.webcam.pro and Rolling with the app and activity of your choice, but this method truly works. Problem Solved!

Comment: You need to know the exact package name and the exact class name of the `Activity` you want to launch. From your question it looks like you do not have the correct names. Also, not all activities from other apps can be launched directly. An `Activity` of another app can only be launched directly by your app if it is declared `android:exported="true"` and isn't covered by a permission that your app doesn't have.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I do know the package name of the app I want to launch. It is com.pas.webcam.pro. The activity or class I want to launch is RollingActivity or simply Rolling. This activity can be launched by a third party app, because the Activity Launcher app in the Play Store can launch this specific, as well as any, activity. So are you saying I need to add something to the manifest of my app? Because I am pretty sure my code is fine. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need anything in your manifest. You need to know the exact package name of the other app (this is in the other app's manifest) and you need to know the exact fully qualified class name of the `Activity` you want to start. This can also be found in the other app's manifest. The fully qualified class name will be something like `com.pas.webcam.pro.Rolling` but it could also be something completely different.

Comment: If you don't have the manifest (or APK) of the other app, there are ways to get this information using `PackageManager`. You can query the `PackageManager` to get information about other installed apps, including the names of activities, etc.

Comment: I am absolutely 100% positive the CORRECT package name is com.pas.webcam.pro. The name of the activity is DEFINITELY Rolling. com.pas.webcam.pro.Rolling is DEFINITELY CORRECT. I do not need to query the Package Manager. I already have the package name and activity to launch. If you are sure I do not have to add anything to the Manifest, which I think is correct, what am i doing wrong? Is my code bad? How do I launch this activity of this package? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to add anything to your manifest. Please edit your post and paste the exact code you are using and the exact error message from logcat.

Comment: I already did. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong now? Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't match the error message. So obviously this is wrong. In any case, the message is clear: You do not have the correct package name and class name for the `Activity` you want to launch. You can tell me you do, but you don't. Your code is fine. You just need the correct package name and fully qualified class name of the `Activity` you want to launch.

Comment: Please view my post again. I added an image of the app and activity I want to launch. Then tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.pas.webcam.pro", "com.pas.webcam.Rolling");
startActivity(intent);
```

Since you refer to the app as "IP webcam pro", I'm assuming the package name is "com.pas.webcam.pro" (found by Internet research).

Comment: Wow! I have been searching for weeks for a solution. I have probably tried 10 different types of code. Yet this short easy line of code works. Thank you, thank you so much. Yes, the package name is com.pas.webcam.pro. I knew that. You are correct. Again, THANK YOU. IT WORKS. Woohoo.

Comment: Glad this solved your problem. You can accept my answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will remove the question from the list of open questions and perhaps help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 13 (API level 33) and higher, the other app needs to define an matching `<intent-filter>` or your app will throw an `ActivityNotFoundException`.
Cf. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#match-intent-filter